# Add cookie manually - Curl PHP

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I would like to know if it's possible to add a cookie with name, value, domain, path, secure, http only and expiry before exec the curl.

I'm looking for it and what I found was only some ways to set the name and value of the cookie. And I also found a lot of ways to add it by using a file, but I would like to add the cookie without the file.

Another question related to the topic:
If I init the curl to make a GET request and then without close the curl I make a POST. Is it possible to use the cookies that the GET request has received to make the POST (without file)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `CURLOPT_COOKIE` cookie option with curl_setopt. Example:

```
<?php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "<cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; Domain=<domain-value>; Path=<path-value>; Secure; HttpOnly; Expires=<date>");
```

more on how to format the cookie header can be found on the man docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

For your second question you simply need to set the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to an empty string to enable cookie

```
<?php
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
```